# How to change a function-based-view to a class-based-view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 1.6.5. Basically what I want is that, when a user clicks the 'delete' link, no form is shown. Just updating the `*_deleted_at` field then show the inbox, without redirecting to the `message_confirm_delete.html` template.

Given the following:

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^delete/(?P<message_id>[\d]+)/$', delete, name='messages_delete'),
...
```

**views.py**

```
def delete(request, message_id, success_url=None):
    user = request.user
    now = timezone.now()
    message = get_object_or_404(Message, id=message_id)
    deleted = False
    if success_url is None:
        success_url = reverse('messages:messages_inbox')
    if 'next' in request.GET:
        success_url = request.GET['next']
    if message.sender == user:
        message.sender_deleted_at = now
        deleted = True
    if message.recipient == user:
        message.recipient_deleted_at = now
        deleted = True
    if deleted:
        message.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
    raise Http404
```

How can I convert the following function based view into a class based view? Not sure which one fits here: `UpdateView` or `DeleteView`.

Comment: Why do you think your requirement will be fulfilled by switching to a class-based view? Class-based and function-based views work in *exactly the same way* as far as the frontend are concerned. Switching will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: Since you are referring to a delete action a DeleteView should be used, in order to add your custom logic, just override the default methods.
http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: And yet I'm not deleting the record. Just updating a field in the model e.g. appears in the trash as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `RedirectView` for this case or any View-class with `DeletionMixin`